# Asterisk in an array in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between sizeof(arr) and sizeof(*arr) in C.

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 0, 5, 5 };
int n = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );
```

Comment: `sizeof(*arr) == sizeof(arr[0]) == sizeof(int(1))`.

Comment: ultimately this question is "What is the difference between `arr` and `*arr`?". When you understand that, then the rest falls into place.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq except the last one was C++

Answer (score 10):

`sizeof(arr)` is the size of the entire array. In your case, it is the size of 5 integers. In case int is 4 bytes it is 5 * 4 = 20.

`*arr` is the first element of the array. It is equal to `arr[0]`. `sizeof(*arr)` is the size of this element. In your case it is 4 bytes.

So `sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );` will give the number of elements in the array.

You should note that this will only work in the scope where the array is defined. If you are passing the array to a function, the `arr` will decay into a pointer and `sizeof (arr)` will only give you the size of a pointer in your system (typically 4 or 8 bytes).